# how to distribute leftover space between buttons

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

Is there any way i can accomplish the following, i've looked around but can't seem to find a solution:

I have 5 buttons inside a LinearLayout and Im defining the buttons width and height programmatically. There is no space between the buttons, so it looks like this:

```
(x=button)
|    xxxxx    |
```

How can I tell the layout to distribute any leftover space on either side of the group of buttons to be evenly distibuted BETWEEN the buttons, making the layout look like this:

```
(x=button)
| x x x x x |
```

Comment: I'm confused; why not set the layout_weight attribute of the buttons? That should spread them out to fill the LinearLayout.

Comment: im defining their width+height in java NOT xml. So xml wont know how to define the weight tag correctly.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, this ain't possible with attributes of your LinearLayout.

You can choose to add an empty view or spacer between your buttons, or give your buttons margin or padding where needed.

Comment: if i add a space view between the buttons how is it possible to change width of space based on width of buttons?

Comment: Give it the correct weight. 1 for the buttons and 0 for the spaces. Or the other way around if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Your layout should look like this: Button Spacer Button Spacer Button Spacer Button. Set the spacers to have width 0dp, weight 1.

Comment: Yes, because the weight value is used by the containing LinearLayout when inflating the view hierarchy.